# Добавить букву к цифре с помощью Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, где идет перечисление цифр через точку c запятой:

```
string str = "12; 13; 14";
```

После последней цифры точка с запятой не ставиться. Как с помощью регулярного выражения в C# добавить к каждой цифре букву `t`?:

```
t12; t13; t14
```

В редакторе Notepad++ я это делаю так:

Найти: `(\d*;|\d*)`

Заменить на: `t\1`

Comment: Все-таки, добавить букву к цифре, или к числу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам поможет метод [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("1234; 13; 14", @"(\d+)", "t$1"));
// Вывод:
// t1234; t13; t14
```

Обратите внимание, я заменил `\1` на `$1`. Кроме того, нет необходимости в дополнительном условии `\d+;` (`+` а не `*` - это важно)

Comment: все верно, спасибо!